# Returning Pointer to Bidimensional Array [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I don't know why but it doesn't return the bidimensional array I declare in the function.

```
char** canvas() {
    
    char canvas[18][8];
    
    fill(canvas[0], canvas[0] + 18 * 8, 'O');
    
    return canvas;
    
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector<int> of size `18 * 8` and emulate the the 2Dness of it. The alternative is manual memory allocation and that turns into a heap of *no fun* in a hurry.

Comment: Note: `char x[a][b]` is in no way compatible with `char**`. One is a 2D array, the other is a pointer to an array *of pointers*. Your compiler should be freaking out. If it isn't, turn on more warnings like `-Wall`.

Comment: Which C++ standard are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`canvas` is a local variable, its lifetime will expire as the function goes out of scope, accessing this variable through a pointer after that will invoke undefined behavior.

The return type of the function is also incompatible with the object you're trying to return.

If you must use *C-style* arrays (inferred from your comment), you can do something like:

```
char (*canvas())[8] //pointer to array return type
{    
    char (*canvas)[8] = new char[18][8]; //C++ manual allocation
 
    //std::fill(canvas[0], canvas[0] + 18 * 8, 'O'); //works
    std::fill_n(canvas[0], 18 * 8, 'O'); //better, as suggested by Ted Lyngmo
    
    return canvas;     
}
```

You can then call it like:

```
int main()
{
    char(*canv)[8] = canvas(); //assign it

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) //use it like a 2D array
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            std::cout << canv[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] canv; //delete object after it's used
}
```

---

As you are using C++ I would suggest a STL container like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), i.e. a vector of vectors `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`, you can also use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as the dimensions are known at compile time i.e. `std::array<std::array<char, 8>, 18>`.

For a C++ `std::array` implementation:

```
std::array<std::array<char, 8>, 18> canvas()
{
    std::array<std::array<char, 8>, 18> canvas;

    std::fill_n(canvas.begin()->begin(), 18 * 8, 'O');

    return canvas;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<char, 8>, 18> canv = canvas();
    //...
}
```

For a `std::vector` implementation:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> canvas()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> canvas{18, std::vector<char>(8, '0')};

    return canvas;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> canv = canvas();
    //...
}
```

In both cases you can use a *C-style* `for` loop like in the first example, but you can also use a range-based for loop wich is better because it avoids reaching outside the array bounds, and therefore avoids undefined behavior.

```
for (auto& a : canv)
{
    for (auto& ch : a)
    {
        std::cout << ch;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

Output in all cases:

```
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOO
```

Comment: `std::array` is not the same thing as an array. It quite rare to use arrays in C++, `std::array` or `std::vector` are almost always superior.

Comment: @john, yes, for sure, but in this case as the dimensions are know at compile time,  it's an option.

Comment: @DiaskyVB If the array bounds are known at compile time then you could use `std::array` but probably your current compiler won't support it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that sounds reasonable, well spotted btw `[]`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, once again, well spotted, I feel I should share the votes with you :)

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misunderstanding that because `char[n]` is convertable to `char*` is must also be possible to convert `char[n][m]` to `char**` but this is not true.

The problem is that the *elements* of `char[n]` and `char*` are the same. Each element is a `char` so the conversion is OK.

But with `char[n][m]` each element is `char[m]` and with `char**` each element is `char*`. These are not the same and the conversion is not valid.

The simple solution is to use vectors instead of arrays.

```
vector<vector<char>> canvas(){
    
    
    vector<vector<char>> canvas(18, vector<char>(8));
    
    fill(canvas[0], canvas[0] + 18 * 8, 'O');
    
    return canvas;
    
    
}
```

Comment: 11 19 [Error] '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list

Comment: @DiaskyVB You must have a very old compiler or you are using it with very old options. But if you must then put a space between `>>`.

Comment: I'm using Devc++ 5.11

Comment: That's a very old compiler, there are modern C++ compilers available for free. You should update.

Comment: Can you suggest one for me?

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows, then [Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/). Don't confuse with Microsoft VS Code which I definitely don't recommend.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is expected to work. You'll fill the memory of the underlying `std::vector<char>`s, not the heap allocated arrays they point at.

Comment: `static_assert(sizeof(std::array<char, 8>) == sizeof(char[8]));` `std::vector<std::array<char, 8>> canvas(18);` `std::fill_n(canvas[0].data(), 18 * 8, 'O');` would work though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, thanks, I copied the OP's code without looking carefully enough at it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a weird syntax:

```
char (*canvas())[8] //pointer to array return type
```

to improve legibility could be useful use type aliases:

```
using canvas_ptr = char (*)[8];
```

So you can write the c-style solution in this way:

```
canvas_ptr getCanvas()
{ 
    canvas_ptr canvas = new char[18][8]; //C++ allocation
    std::cout << "size:" << std::size(canvas) << '\n';
    std::fill_n(canvas[0], 18 * 8, 'O'); //as suggested by Ted Lyngmo
    
    return canvas;
}


int main()
{
    canvas_ptr c = getCanvas();

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) //use it like a 2D array
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            std::cout << c[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] c; //delete object after it's used
}
```